# Русское слово палисадник

Tags: этимология

Среди сложных для москвичей слов на "Тотальном диктанте" стали "чересчур", "струганый" и "палисадник". https://ria.ru/society/20180416/1518743066.html

Что ясно по этимологии, и русское ли слово *палисадник*?

Comment: Вопрос из серии "погуглите за меня"? Слово русское. Происходит от французского _palissade_  - "изгородь, частокол".

Comment: Вопрос на спорную тему из серии «выбери по душе». Слово русское, от русского же: есть такая т. з.

Answer (score 1):

**Шанский**, прекрасно изучив, откуда ноги растут, считает ***палисадник*** ИСКОННЫМ, то есть нашим, родным! Потому что он суффиксально образован от своего исторического родственника, который в свою очередь столь же отчаянно суффиксально образован от своего!..

[**ПАЛИСАДНИК**](https://etymological.academic.ru/3459/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

> Искон. Суф. производное от *палисад* — тж. < франц. *palissade,*
>   которое восходит к прованс. *palissada,* суф. производному от
>   *palissa* «частокол», суф. образованию от *palus* «кол».

Немножко шире, с толкованиями, рассматривает слово **[словарь Семенова](http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Palisadnik-1305.html)**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и **[Фасмер](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-9172.htm)** одаряет нас своими пятью копейками, что дорогого стоят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда над этим не задумывалась. А ведь действительно слово во времена Петра пришло как иноязычное (частокол), а народом освоено как своё со исконным значением (полусад) - маленький садик и используется в обоих значениях.